# How can I convert a .cue / .bin ( with cdr tracks) image into a single .iso file?

Tags: shell, iso, data-cd, audio-cd

How can I convert a .cue / .bin (cdr track) image into a single .iso file?

I have 
Fedora 16 (x86-64)

```
Linux 3.1.9-1.fc16.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 13 16:37:42 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should look at `bchunk`, which is specifically meant for this type of conversion.  You should be able to install it with `sudo yum install bchunk`, but I'm only 95% sure it's in the standard repo. `bchunk` will create an ISO from any data tracks, and CDR for any CD audio.  If you want everything in one ISO `bchunk` is not appropriate.

The syntax is like this,

```
bchunk IMAGE.bin IMAGE.cue IMAGE.iso
```

To create a single ISO with all the tracks in one take a look at `bin2iso`.  `bin2iso` is most likely not included in your standard repo.   Although RPMs do exist unofficially online.  I prefer PowerISO over `bin2iso`, as `bin2iso` is fairly non-updated.

```
bin2iso <cuefile>
```

You could also do the conversion using [PowerISO](http://www.poweriso.com/download.htm).
It is commercial software, but the linux version is freeware.  Sometimes if I have problems with the Free Software for different image conversions, I give PowerISO a go.

Comment: i have tried that tool but the proccess create 2 file (1 .iso file and .cdr file) i want to merge both files into a single iso any ideas ?

Comment: That .cdr is a CD Audio file, which would make that BIN/CUE a multitrack Audio/Data disc. Which i'm guessing is why it was simpler to go BIN/CUE.  I'm looking for an answer if this is posible.  Is this for use in an Emu?

Comment: really this might be time to attempt this with PowerISO, It seems to handle everything so clean.  Its a shame our CD opensource tools are so deficient.

Comment: I updated my answer, your not going to get much more complete than this.

Comment: yeah i'm trying to use the iso in a old system emulator

Comment: Woah, nice to see `PowerISO` is available on linux, and free. That was one of the essential apps for Windows.

Answer (score 11):

If the BIN file contains CD-Audio tracks you cannot convert it to an ISO image! The reason for this is that, unlike e.g. a CD-ROM, the data structure of an audio CD is fundamentally incompatible with an ISO 9660 file system. See the link below for a paper that gives a good explanation of this:

http://journal.code4lib.org/articles/9581

However, you could use *bchunk* (as suggested above) with the *-w* option, which generates output in WAV format. Command line would be something like this:

```
bchunk -s -w IMAGE.bin IMAGE.cue IMAGE
```

This will create WAV files for each audio track, e.g.:

```
IMAGE001.wav
IMAGE002.wav
```

Etcetera. The *-s* switch does a byte swap on the audio samples. If you omit it, the Endianness of the WAVs will be wrong, and they will play as static noise (a least that's what happened when I last tried).

Answer (score 0):

First use imgburner software which will make two different ISOs of bin and cue files. Then extract both the ISOs in one folder using Winrar.

Then one bin file will be created merged with cue file and after all convert the bin to ISO using the tool bin2iso.

Answer (score 0):

**cdmage** loads in multi track files and saves them to 1 cue+bin file.
Just tested it on psx Lucky Luke with 21 tracks and game runs smooth on my emulator after.

Answer (score -5):

Find it!

```
diskfile1.iso
diskfile2.iso
```

to merge to result.iso

```
cat diskfile1.iso > result.iso
cat diskfile2.iso >> result.iso
```

done.